# How can I use SQLite ADO.net data provider?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, ado.net

I have [a .NET 4.5 application](https://github.com/mns-csharp/GreQuizApplication) which is up and running. This application can connect to SQL Server and MS Access database files.

Now, I want to use an SQLite database.

So, I downloaded SQLite ADO.net 4.5 data provider (***sqlite-netFx45-setup-x64-2012-1.0.117.0.exe***) from [this link](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads-unsup.wiki) and installed it on my laptop.

My connection string is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="assemblies" type="Simple.Framework.AssembliesConfigurationSection, Simple.Framework"/>
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="MyMSAccessConnStr" 
         connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\DB\access_db_file.mdb;Persist Security Info=False" 
         providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>-->
    <!--<add name="MySQLServerConnStr" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=gre;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>-->
    <add name="MySQLiteConnStr" connectionString="Data Source=C:\DB\sqlite_db_file.db;Version=3;"
         providerName="System.Data.SQLite"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <startup>
    
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/></startup>

</configuration>
```

In the above, `MyMSAccessConnStr` and `MySqlServerConnStr` are already working without an issue.

However, the SQLite connection is not working. It is giving the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  
It may not be installed.
```

I also don't see the `System.Data.Sqlite` in the GAC.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because the `System.Data.SQLite` ADO.Net db provider is unknown to your system.

You can either install it in the GAC yourself and declare it in machine.config as explained here: [Obtaining a DbProviderFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/obtaining-a-dbproviderfactory)

But you [don't need to install it in the GAC](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/raw/96f3932f9f371cca172dbeecfd5353c68e29d3e7):

- declare it in your `app.config` like this:

  ```
    <configuration>
        <connectionStrings>
            <add name="PTSystemMSAccess" connectionString="Data Source=c:\mypath\my.db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite"/>
        </connectionStrings>

        <system.data>
            <DbProviderFactories>
                <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
                <add name="SQLite Data Provider"
                    invariant="System.Data.SQLite"
                    description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite"
                    type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
            </DbProviderFactories>
        </system.data>

    </configuration>
  ```
- just copy `System.Data.SQLite.dll` and `SQLite.Interop.dll` aside your `QuizApplication.exe` file.

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: Yes, I've tested it with your app and this ORM (w/o the real db of course). BadImageFormatException is a x64 vs x86 issue, you've copied the wrong System.Data.SQLite

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.

Comment: This is totally different issue. Make sure you're copying the good dll https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsmmEDGvydk2uwr0DZKS7AVjmEVw?e=A0yGbv

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you include the <system.data> element in your config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="assemblies" type="Simple.Framework.AssembliesConfigurationSection, Simple.Framework"/>
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="MyMSAccessConnStr" 
         connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\DB\access_db_file.mdb;Persist Security Info=False" 
         providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>-->
    <!--<add name="MySQLServerConnStr" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=gre;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>-->
    <add name="MySQLiteConnStr" connectionString="Data Source=C:\DB\sqlite_db_file.db;Version=3;"
         providerName="System.Data.SQLite"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <startup>
    
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/></startup>

  <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
            <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite"
           type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

</configuration>
```

Additionally make sure that the SQLite dll's are copied to your output directory when building/debugging/releasing (typically the bin folder):
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4afd.png)

Comment: Edited with where to add in config and screenshot of dlls that need to be present when running in bin folder

Comment: Have what I posted above? SQLite is a little finicky in terms of getting it to work. Try adding the <system.data> entry I mentioned in your config. For the SQLite dlls, go to References in your project, and for each SQLite reference, go to it's Properties and set "Copy Local" to true and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I am using a custom ORM. Your code won't be read by my ORM.

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework?